# Show that $\log[(1+i)^2]\neq 2\log(1+i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

The problem is as stated in the title. I found that the $\mathrm{Log}[(1+i)^2] = 2\mathrm{Log}(1+i)$. We know that
$$\mathrm{Log}(z)=\ln(r)+i\theta$$
Now, without defining a branch, doesn't that mean that
$$\log(z)=\ln(r)+i(\theta +2\pi k), \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
doesn't converge to any finite point? This was a question that I had on an exam and it's been bothering me as to how one would show
$$\log[(1+i)^2]\neq 2\log(1+i)$$
It seems like you can just jump to the non-convergence conclusion. But, my thinking seems to often send me down a wrong path, so if someone could help clear this up for me, I'd be much obliged!

Comment: Convergence? What are you talking about? Why are you talking about the limit points of the set of possible values for $\log z$? A branch must be chosen to do this problem, and it has nothing to do with what you're talking about.

Comment: The qustion is : Is $\ln(ab) =\ln a + \ln b$ ?

Comment: @blue just my minimal understanding of the complex logarithm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem in CA, but it is mispresented in the case of the OP.

The correct question (as it appears on Churchill and Brown for example) is:

> If $\log(z)$ denotes the complex logarithm and $z\in\mathbb{C}$, show that it $\mathit{MAY}$ happen that $\log(z^2)\neq 2\log(z)$ (or with some other particular example which breaks the power rule...)

Not that it WILL happen, afortiori.

Like many commenters already said, this depends on the choice of branch of the complex function $\log$ one takes, but there's more to it than just that.

If the same branch is chosen for both cases, the result is equality. To dispel notions to the contrary, with Maple:

> z0 := (1+I)^2;
>   z1 := 1+I;
>
> CLog := proc (k, z) local theta, rho;
>
> rho := op(1, polar(z)); theta := op(2, polar(z));
>
> ln(rho)+I*(theta+2*k*Pi) end proc;

and using the same branch, we have:

> CLog(0, z0);

ln(2)+(1/2*I)*Pi

> 2*CLog(0, z1);

ln(2)+(1/2*I)*Pi

Different pairs of $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ in the previous, will of course break equality.

There is, however, a different reason why equality may break: A different $\mathit{definition}$ of the complex function $\log$.

The standard definition used most often with the cut being the negative axis, is:

$$\log(k,z)=\ln(|z|)+(\arg(z)+2k\pi)i,\text{with:}\arg(z)\in(-\pi,\pi], k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

One, however, may define the complex $\log$ function to admit a branch cut starting from zero (where the function is not even defined) and extending out to infinity towards any direction one wants, so if one defines for example:

$$\log^*(k,z)=\ln(|z|)+(\arg(z)+2k\pi)i,\text{with:}\arg(z)\in(2\pi/p-2\pi,2\pi/p],k\in\mathbb{Z},p\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$$

then this is a perfectly good definition for the complex $\log$ map, but will break many such equalities if one chooses $\arg$ lying on opposite sides of the cut depending on the complex values given, thus the inequality for specific examples.

Concluding, equality may break not only with different branches but also with different definitions of $\log$.

Comment: The problem was given on an exam of mine, so I just stated the problem as my professor gave it. I just used an example (defined a specific branch) to show the equality did not hold and did not understand why he marked my answer wrong. Thank you for the in depth explanation!

Comment: @user30625: you are welcome. To make things a little clearer: To show inequality, you need to, either 1) choose different branches for the logarithm of the two expressions, OR 2) choose different definitions of the complex log function for the two expressions. Otherwise you cannot show inequality. This is probably why your professor marked your answer wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+i)^2=2i\implies\log[(1+i)^2]=\log2+\log(i)=\log2+\frac{i\pi}2$$  as $i=e^{\dfrac{i\pi}2}$

$\displaystyle \log(1+i)=\log(\sqrt2e^{\dfrac{i\pi}4})=\frac{\log 2}2+\dfrac{i\pi}4$

What can we deduce from this?

Comment: You're only only looking at the principle part; Log(z). $log(z)=ln(r) + i(\theta + 2\pi k)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. :\

Comment: @user30625, I think by convention, $\text{log}$ represents general values, $\log$ represents principal one

Comment: @user30625 Like I told you; a branch must be chosen to do this problem. There's no multivalued stuff involved here. (Note that for most choices of branch, it *is* an equality, so the problem strikes me as strange - what branch are you supposed to use?)

Comment: @user30625, I meant $\text{Log}$ represents general values (conventionally)

Comment: @blue exactly the problem I'm having. No branch defined and yet my professor expected us to show that $log(z^2)\neq 2log(z)$. I defined my own branch which turned out wrong. 
$$\\$$
After showing the the principle parts were equal, I thought that the general would be equal.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee In my book, the principle part is defined as $Log(z)$ and the general is defined as $log(z)$, so that's why I've been using the notation as such